# How to plot matrix vs matrix

Tags: matlab

I have two 3 x 4 matrices. I want to make a 2D plot of this but can't seem to plot it correctly. I am being shown multiple lines (but the plotting should be element by element).

Here is my code. Any suggestion?

```
X=[1 2 5 7; 2 4 6 1; 2 5 6 2]
Y=X.^0.5

plot(X(:),Y(:));
```

**Edit**
just to be more clear, what I am trying to do here is plot X vs Y. taking into account the below example, when

```
 X= element(0,0); Y=element(0,0).
```

similarly, when

```
X= element(0,1); Y=element(0,1)
```

and so on... Using this method, the graph will be plotted using those values (element by element) and we will get a 2D line plot of X vs Y=X.^0.5. I hope this clarifies what I am looking for.

X =

```
 1     2     5     7
 2     4     6     1
 2     5     6     2
```

Y =

```
1.0000    1.4142    2.2361    2.6458
1.4142    2.0000    2.4495    1.0000
1.4142    2.2361    2.4495    1.4142

Plot(X(:), Y(:)) may not be the right command so I am basically looking for edits in this.
```

Comment: X(:) is not monotonic: it runs backwards at the end, drawing a line back to the beginning.  What do you want to do with the data?  Sort the pairs by X?  Discard the backwards points?  Leave out the line and just draw points?

Comment: element(0,0) was just an example to tell that whatever value is at this position of X and Y should be plotted on the graph with X against Y. similarly, the next value in the graph will be the element on (0,1) of X and Y and so on. regarding the 3 x 4 matrix, again this is just an example. My main question is how to make a single line 2D plot/graph of X against Y, where both X and Y are matrices.

Comment: Your extra information still doesn't answer the question.  Your command is doing exactly what you ask it to.  But your X runs backward, which means your plot will also run backward, making it look like multiple lines.  This has nothing to do with matrices.  Use this as an example, and explain how you'd connect the points: `plot([1 2 3 1], [1 2 4 1])`

Comment: @user2743295: Btw, there is no `element(0,0)` in MATLAB. The first element in a matrix is in `(1,1)`.

Comment: @RobertP. i already know that. i was simply stating a mathematical example. I think focus should be on the solution and not the arbitraty example for others understanding that was provided

Comment: @RobertP. no problem at all. I will try to post a screenshot of what i am looking for and try to explain better so that I can find the solution. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Daniel and Eitan have answered your question quite well, but here are some alternatives for you. I guess one of them should fit your needs:

If you just want a line representing `X` vs `X^0.5`:

```
X = linspace(0,7,100);
plot(X,X.^0.5)
```

or, if you want only the integer values of `X` and displayed as a scatter plot:

```
X = 0:7;
scatter(X, X.`0.5)
```

or, if you want to plot the matrices, element by element **sorted**:

```
plot(sort(X(:)),sort(Y(:)))
```

and as a scatter plot:

```
scatter(sort(X(:)),sort(Y(:)))
```

or, if you want it element by element, do as Eitan and Danial suggests:

```
scatter(X(:),Y(:))
plot(X(:),Y(:))
```

The last one will look like two lines, but it is really just one going back and forth.

Comment: do you think we can get rid of the multiple lines and only have a single line plot? any suggestions?

Comment: I think you are missing something here. The matrices you want to plot will be a loop (thus looking like two lines). Use the sorted version, that will give only one line... or `plot(X(1:10),Y(1:10))`

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for but did set me in the right direction. i will accept this answer. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for a scatter plot?

```
scatter(X(:), Y(:))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want any lines, you have to set a line spec.

```
plot(X(:),Y(:),'x');
```